# Facebook "like" button shows count of homepage instead specific article

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a website with a news section, and I want to put individual "like" buttons in each post. The problem is that the buttons shows the root like count and not the count of that specific page/post.

And the weirdest is that it works in one of the pages, but not in the others.

[This](http://eepolitecnica.org.br/noticias/jornal_nacional_exibe_materia_sobre_o_eep/) is the page with the buttons working and [this](http://eepolitecnica.org.br/noticias/valor_poli_cria_primeiro_fundo_de_universidade/) is one of the pages where te button isn't working.

I've already read all the content of facebook's social plugin and open graph, and I still don't understand what's happening.

This button don't work:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=218284238205675&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://eepolitecnica.org.br/noticias/valor_poli_cria_primeiro_fundo_de_universidade/" send="true" layout="button_count" width="150" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

and this works fine:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=170199966377672&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://eepolitecnica.org.br/noticias/jornal_nacional_exibe_materia_sobre_o_eep" send="true" layout="button_count" width="150" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

These are some relevant meta tags I have

```
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $base_url, $site_url; ?>" />
```

Is that a common bug from FB's Like button as it seems or I'm really doing something wrong?

Sorry about my terrible english...

Answer (score 2):

Remove the trailing slash in the version that doesn't work. This trailing slash is causing your urls not to match and so facebook is defaulting back to the base url

eg:

```
<fb:like href="http://eepolitecnica.org.br/noticias/valor_poli_cria_primeiro_fundo_de_universidade" send="true" layout="button_count" width="150" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

Comment: I already tried this, but it didn't work. The like button of this url mysteriously worked when I generated another button on FB developers page. But the one in http://eepolitecnica.org.br/noticias/folha_de_s_paulo_publica_materia_sobre_o_eep/ isn't working...

Comment: Yes I tried regenerating it as well without the slash and thats what I thought would fix it. Try removing the majority of the metadata until you can find where its choking up?

Answer (score 1):

Try using FB's linter tool:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Enter the URL for your different pages and see what FB is actually seeing from the XFBML tags on your page. This might shed more light or post back results here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>

<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/account-name" send="true" layout="button_count" width="150" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```